# How to assign fileencoding's value to a variable?

Tags: variables

In ex mode,i get the value for `set fileencoding`.

```
set fileencoding?
fileencoding=utf-8
```

How can assign `str` with the value `utf-8` and print it?

```
let str=`set fileencoding?`  #it is a wrong statement,i just want to express my meaning
echo str
```

Comment: `:h :let-option`

Comment: `let str = &fileencoding`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `&` prefix to refer to option values as part of Vimscript expressions (or to set them using `let` statements.)

See [`:help :let-option`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option) for more details.

In your specific case, you can use:

```
let str = &fileencoding
```